# BizTalk 2013 with Sharepoint Adapter Error Undefined

Tags: view, sharepoint-2013, biztalk, csom, biztalk-2013r2

I use BizTalk 2013 R2 with SharePoint 2013.

In the SharePoint is the Document Library "**EN**". The "EN" Document Library contains the Folder "**IN**". Because the SharePoint Adapter can only listen on Document Libraries, I did a Library View "**EN_IN**" to show all Documents in a flat structure.

So I configured the CSOM Adapter like this

```
SharePoint Site URL => http://servername/sites/xy/
Source Document Library URL => EN
View Name => EN_IN
```

Then the error occurred:

> The Windows SharePoint Services adapter has completed gathering the list and document library information from the SharePoint site http://servername/sites/xy.
>
> the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table

How do I resolve this?

Comment: If you still need a solution, is there any other information provided in the event viewer (on either the Biztalk or Sharepoint server). And it looks like others have resolved this issue by restarting the Biztalk or Sharepoint servers: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9f1a1476-7f92-4edc-b8c2-16228e51e77a/anyone-ever-encountered-this?forum=biztalkgeneral